# Not able to rename my file copied from Windows to Mac

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems

I have copied a file from a windows system to my mac system. I want to rename this file but it is probably read only. How can I rename the file?

I tried it through terminal also but got the error

`mv: rename education.jpg to logo.jpg: Operation not permitted`

Comment: could you do `ls -dla .` and `ls -dla education.jpg`. looking at the permissions and ownership of the files and directories involved would make this simple to solve.

Comment: hi dan I found following on ls -dla education.jpg -rwx------  1

Comment: good but when renaming files it's the perissions on the containing directory that matter which is why i stated `ls -dla .` and the ownership of the files is important as mode `-rwx------` says that the owner of this file has read write and execute permission but the group or world has none but it doesn't say who the owner is and without that it's not possible to answer that.

Comment: ok i did that too drwx------+ 12 espireinfolabs  staff  408 Sep 26 13:34 .

Comment: is `espireinfolabs` the same as your current user as stated by `whoami`? otherwise you should take ownership of the files and directories by doing `sudo chown $(whoami) <copied_files_and_directories>`.

Comment: Dan, There is only one account in my system and that too is admin account. I tried sudo chown $(whoami) <copied_files_and_directories> but I am getting option to add password and terminal is not accepting mt password

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1436/discussion-between-pankaj-and-dan-d)